# Using php for abbreviating the states in a drop down menu

Tags: php, database, text

I'm back once again, I know you guys are probably tired of me lol but there are somethings I figured out how to add the text boxes. I am still having trouble with the drop down menu. I am supposed to have a drop down menu that has the list of the states and when you submit it, it will be abbreviated but that doesn't want to work for me either. I'm pretty sure it is something easy to fix and I keep over looking it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lab 7, Part 1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" action="http://weblab.kennesaw.edu/formtest.php"
        onsubmit="return validateForm()"
              method = "post">
        <h1 style="text-align:center">Lab 7, Part 1</h1>
        <h2 style="text-align:center">IT 3203</h2>
        <a href="index.html"><p style="text-align:center">Main Page!</p></a>
        <table>
        <th>Fruits For Sale!</th>
        <tr><th>Fruits</th><th>Weight</th><th>Price</th></tr>
         <?php
        $db=mysqli_connect(null,null,null,'weblab')
or die("Can't connect to DB:" . mysqli_connect_error());
        $q = " select fruit_item_no, fruit_name, fruit_weight, fruit_price";
        $q .= " from fruit_t";
        $q .= " order by fruit_name;";
        $dbResult = mysqli_query($db,$q);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($dbResult);
        if ($num == 0) {
         echo '<tr><td colspan="2">';
        echo 'Database query retrieved zero rows.</td></tr>';
}
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
        $name = $row['fruit_name'];
        $weight = $row['fruit_weight'];
        $price = $row['fruit_price'];
        echo "<tr><td><b>$name</b></td>";
        echo "<td>$weight</td>";
        echo "<td>$price</td>";
        echo "<td><input type='text' name='name'></td></tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
        <br>
        <label>First Name
            <input type="text"
                   name="firstname" id="firstname"
                   size="25" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Last Name
 <input type="text"
                   name="lastname" id="lastname"
                   size="25" />
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Street Address
            <input type="text"
                   name="streetaddress" id="streetaddress"
                   size="35" />
  </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>City
            <input type="text"
                   name="city" id="city"
                   size="25" />
        </label>
        <label>State:
    <select name="state" id="state">
  <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect(null,null,null,'weblab')
     or die("Can't connect to DB:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    $q = " select state_abbr, state_name";
    $q .= " from state_t";
    $q .= " order by state_name;";
    while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
    $state_abbr = $x["state_abbr"];
    $state_name = $x["state_name"];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $state_abbr; ?>">
    <?php echo $state_name; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
        </select>
<?php
}
?>
</label>
 <br>
        <br>
        <label>Zip code:
            <input type="text"
                   name="zipcode" id="zipcode"
                   size="20" />

        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
<label>Visa
            <input type="radio" name="pref_payment"
                   id="pref_payment_visa" value="visa" checked />
        </label><br>
        <label>MasterCard
            <input type="radio" name="pref_payment"
                   id="pref_payment_master" value="master" checked />
        </label><br>
        <label>American Express
            <input type="radio" name="pref_payment"
 id="pref_payment_american" value="american" checked />
        </label><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you define `$state_id`?

Comment: @madforstrength oops okay I fixed it to say $state_abbr but it still says that it is a syntax error, unexpected '}'

Comment: It gives error On which line?

Comment: line 87 @madforstrength

Comment: You have all sorts of issues going on, the worst of which probably being the fact you have HTML in your PHP code from your closing table tag down.

Comment: I didn't post the entire code. One the code that was acting up. Do you want to see the entire code? @Dontfeedthecode

Comment: @ChynnaDoll 1) We can only see what you paste in here. 2) That doesn't change the fact you have started writing HTML before closing your PHP tags.

Comment: @Dontfeedthecode 1.) I will be more than happy to post the entire code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is why [code indentation](http://mrbool.com/importance-of-code-indentation/29079) is so important.. You were missing closing PHP tags at two places. Refer to below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lab 7, Part 1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myform" action="http://weblab.kennesaw.edu/formtest.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method = "post">

            <h1 style="text-align:center">Lab 7, Part 1</h1>
            <h2 style="text-align:center">IT 3203</h2>
            <a href="index.html"><p style="text-align:center">Main Page!</p></a>
            <table>
                <th>Fruits For Sale!</th>
                <tr><th>Fruits</th><th>Weight</th><th>Price</th></tr>
                <?php
                    $db = mysqli_connect(null,null,null,'weblab')
                        or die("Can't connect to DB:" . mysqli_connect_error());
                    $q = " select fruit_item_no, fruit_name, fruit_weight, fruit_price";
                    $q .= " from fruit_t";
                    $q .= " order by fruit_name;";
                    $dbResult = mysqli_query($db,$q);
                    $num = mysqli_num_rows($dbResult);
                    if ($num == 0) 
                    {
                        echo '<tr><td colspan="2">';
                        echo 'Database query retrieved zero rows.</td></tr>';
                    }
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) 
                    {
                        $name = $row['fruit_name'];
                        $weight = $row['fruit_weight'];
                        $price = $row['fruit_price'];
                        echo "<tr><td><b>$name</b></td>";
                        echo "<td>$weight</td>";
                        echo "<td>$price</td>";
                        echo "<td><input type='text' name='name'></td></tr>\n";
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
            <br>
            <label>First Name
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" size="25" />
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Last Name
                <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" size="25" />
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Street Address
                <input type="text" name="streetaddress" id="streetaddress" size="35" />
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>City
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="25" />
            </label>
            <label>State:
                <select name="state" id="state">
                    <?php
                        $db = mysqli_connect(null,null,null,'weblab')
                            or die("Can't connect to DB:" . mysqli_connect_error());
                        $q = " select state_abbr, state_name";
                        $q .= " from state_t";
                        $q .= " order by state_name;";
                        $dbResult_state = mysqli_query($db,$q);
                        while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult_state))  
                        {
                            $state_abbr = $x["state_abbr"];
                            $state_name = $x["state_name"];
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $state_abbr; ?>">
                            <?php echo $state_name; ?></option>
                            <?php
                        } ?>
                </select>
                <?php } ?> <!-- remove this -->
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Zip code:
                <input type="text" name="zipcode" id="zipcode" size="20" />
            </label>
            <br>
            <br>
            <label>Visa
                <input type="radio" name="pref_payment" id="pref_payment_visa" value="visa" checked />
            </label>
            <br>
            <label>MasterCard
                <input type="radio" name="pref_payment" id="pref_payment_master" value="master" checked />
            </label>
            <br>
            <label>American Express
                <input type="radio" name="pref_payment" id="pref_payment_american" value="american" checked />
            </label>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still isn't working. I probably more than likely messed something up.

Comment: @ChynnaDoll, you are having an unnecessary `}` after `</select>`. Remove that

Comment: Thank you but the states still aren't popping up. This is frustrating @Suyog

Comment: this is because you haven't fired the states query. use `$dbResult = mysqli_query($db,$q);` before `while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) `

Comment: O.O omg I am so slow. I completely forgot about that. Thank you for helping me and having the patience to help me. @Suyog

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $db=mysqli_connect(null,null,null,'weblab')
    or die("Can't connect to DB:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    $q = " select fruit_item_no, fruit_name, fruit_weight, fruit_price";
    $q .= " from fruit_t";
    $q .= " order by fruit_name;";
    $dbResult = mysqli_query($db,$q);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($dbResult);
    if ($num == 0) {
     echo '<tr><td colspan="2">';
    echo 'Database query retrieved zero rows.</td></tr>';
    }
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
$name = $row['fruit_name'];
$weight = $row['fruit_weight'];
$price = $row['fruit_price'];
echo "<tr><td><b>$name</b></td>";
echo "<td>$weight</td>";
echo "<td>$price</td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='name'></td></tr>\n";
?>
</table>
<label>State:
    <select name="state" id="state">
     <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect(null,null,null,'weblab')
     or die("Can't connect to DB:" . mysqli_connect_error());
    $q = " select state_abbr, state_name";
    $q .= " from state_t";
    $q .= " order by state_name;";
    $dbResult = mysqli_query($db,$q);
    while ($x = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbResult)) {
    $state_abbr = $x["state_abbr"];
    $state_name = $x["state_name"];
?>
<option value="<?php echo $state_id; ?>">
    <?php echo $state_name; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
        </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Still isn't working. I'm sorry, I probably did something stupid.

Comment: @ChynnaDoll what do you mean by not working? is it giving any error? if yes on which  line?

Comment: The } isn't supposed to go there after </select>, @Suyog pointed it out so I fixed it but the states aren't showing up.

Comment: @ChynnaDoll you were missing `$dbResult = mysqli_query($db,$q);` before while check updated code

Comment: Thank you for your help. @madforstrength